# Rails 4 how to calculate sum for each method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sum

I'm trying to find solution how to calculate sum for each method in rails.
I feel like tried hundreds different approaches, but couldn't quiet figure it out yet.

For example:
Helper return 2 ids for products: (using alert just to make it visible)

```
view_context.time_plus.each
```

returns 1,2
But when I combine it with call, and selecting multiple option it is only returns last one instead of sum for both value

```
view_context.time_plus.each do |i|
  flash[:alert] =  [Service.find_by_price_id(i).time].sum
end
```

I see in logs call made for both value:

```
 Service Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `services`.* FROM `services` WHERE `services`.`price_id` = 0 LIMIT 1
 Service Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `services`.* FROM `services` WHERE `services`.`price_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find_by_column always returns only one record.

You can use where condition for multiple ids like this

```
Model.where(column_name: [array_of_ids])
```

if view_context.time_plus returns an array of ids

```
Service.where(price_id: view_context.time_plus]).sum(:time)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 flash[:alert] = view_context.time_plus.map{|i| Service.find_by_price_id(i).time}.sum
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use inject method:

```
sum = view_context.time_plus.inject(0) { |sum,i| sum+=Service.find_by_price_id(i).time }
```

But if you are using ruby on rails, better way is use active_record and sql:

```
sum2 = Service.where(price_id: [1,2]).sum(:time)
```